# Genus in Falting's Theorem

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-curves

Falting's Theorem states that algebraic curves of genus $g>1$ have only finitely many rational points on them. But how exactly is $g$ defined here?

The notion of genus here obviously shouldn't come from considering singular homology of the solution set, which is necessarily discrete as a subset of $\mathbb Q^2$. How is the genus defined, then? I looked this up on wikipedia but it isn't explained very clearly anywhere. My guess was that it should be [arithmetic genus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_genus), where in the article it is implied that
$$ g= (-1)^n (\chi(\mathcal O_C)-1)$$
But what's $n$? And what should be the structure sheaf $\mathcal O_C$? Perhaps etale sheaf, with $\chi$ calculated as alternating sum of its dimensions...? (I only know etale cohomology concept superficially; I'm only guessing that this should be the case because etale cohomology appeared as a natural cohomology theory for "arithmetic" curves)

But really, I'm confused. How is $g$ defined?

Comment: http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Genus_of_a_curve

Comment: It's the topological genus of the compact Riemann surface made up with the complex points of the curve.

Comment: So it's just as if we considered the curve is over $\mathbb C$ instead?